# Electron add resource file on package

Tags: electron, packaging, enoent

I am building my first electron app, but I cant package it.

When I am testing using `npm start` everything works but when I tried to package it and when it done, I run it, but I am getting something like this `ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat`.

I have some source like this.

```
fs.copy(path.resolve('src/app/resource/'), dir + '/resource/', e => {
                if (e) {
                    reject(e);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(true);
            });
```

That will copy files to the specified directory and it seem this is the cause of the error.

**Edit:**

I enable the devtools and create installer for windows, but just got this.
[image]
It seems my files is not included on the build.

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "exporter",
  "productName": "Exporter",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "",
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": "",
    "url": "none"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager . --out=/mnt/Busy\\ Drive/dist/exporter --asar --overwrite --all",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build -wl"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "config": "^1.28.1",
    "electron-debug": "^1.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^4.0.2",
    "is-electron-renderer": "^2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.13.0",
    "winston": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "devtron": "^1.1.0",
    "electron": "^1.8.1",
    "electron-builder": "^19.47.1",
    "electron-builder-squirrel-windows": "^19.47.0",
    "electron-packager": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "no-id",
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "dir"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    }
  }
}
```

I already tried different packager but still without success.
Is there wrong on my package.json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit is using the `path.resolve`, you should use`path.join(__dirname, 'your/path/here')`, so it can access the asar file.